# Print the contents of a pop up modal window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to print the contents of a pop up modal window and nothing else on the main page.

I've tried linking a button on the popup window to run the command window.print(); but this just prints a blank page.
I'm assuming that this is because I have not actually called the main content to be printed, but they are in javascript and I simply don't know how to do this.

How can I only print the contents of the pop up window?

The print button is here:

```
<div id="scheduleModal" class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
<h4 class="modal-title_logindetail"></h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body_logindetail">
</div>
<div id="printarea2">
<div class="modal-footer">
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="printArea2('printableArea')" >Print</a>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><?php echo $this->lang->line('cancel'); ?></button>
</div>                       
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

This is what I want to print:

```
    $(document).on('click', '.schedule_modal', function () {
        $('.modal-title_logindetail').html("");
        $('.modal-title_logindetail').html("<?php echo $this->lang->line('login_details'); ?>");
        var base_url = '<?php echo base_url() ?>';
        var student_id = '<?php echo $student["id"] ?>';
        var student_first_name = '<?php echo $student["firstname"] ?>';
        var student_last_name = '<?php echo $student["lastname"] ?>';
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: base_url + "student/getlogindetail",
            data: {'student_id': student_id},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                var data = "";
                data += '<div class="col-md-12">';
                data += '<div class="table-responsive">';
                data += '<p class="lead text text-center" style="font-size:60px;">' + student_first_name + ' ' + student_last_name + '</p>';
                data += '<table class="table table-hover">';
                data += '<thead>';
                data += '<tr>';
                data += '<th class="text text-center" style="font-size:40px;">' + "<?php echo $this->lang->line('user_type'); ?>" + '</th>';
                data += '<th class="text text-center" style="font-size:40px;">' + "<?php echo $this->lang->line('username'); ?>" + '</th>';
                data += '<th class="text text-center" style="font-size:40px;">' + "<?php echo $this->lang->line('password'); ?>" + '</th>';
                data += '</tr>';
                data += '</thead>';
                data += '<tbody>';
                $.each(response, function (i, obj) {
                    data += '<tr>';
                    data += '<td class="text text-center" style="font-size:30px;"><b>' + firstToUpperCase(obj.role) + '</b></td>';
                    data += '<input type=hidden name=userid id=userid value=' + obj.id + '>';
                    data += '<td class="text text-center" style="font-size:30px;">' + obj.username + '</td> ';
                    data += '<td class="text text-center" style="font-size:30px;">' + obj.password + '</td> ';
                    data += '</tr>';
                });
                data += '</tbody>';
                data += '</table>';
                data += '<b class="lead text text-danger" style="font-size:20px;"> ' + "<?php echo $this->lang->line('login_url'); ?>" + ': ' + base_url + 'site/userlogin</b>';              
                data += '</div>  ';
                data += '</div>  ';
                $('.modal-body_logindetail').html(data);
                $("#scheduleModal").modal('show');
            }
        });
    });

    function firstToUpperCase(str) {
        return str.substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() + str.substr(1);
    }
</script>
```

```
<script>
function printArea2(areaID) {
var printContent = document.getElementById("printarea2");
var WinPrint = window.open('', '', 'width=1100,height=650');
WinPrint.document.write(printContent.innerHTML);
WinPrint.document.close();
WinPrint.focus();
WinPrint.print();
WinPrint.close();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using CSS to hide the content you don't want to print? You can do this using `@media print {}` in your CSS.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media#Examples

Comment: A blank page shows up when I click the print button. What I want is to print the javascript element, which I don't know how to.

Comment: A blank page shows up when I click the print button. What I want is to print the javascript element, which I don't know how to.

Comment: ```onclick="printArea2('printableArea')```
there is no element with id printableArea. your code refers to printing div with id printarea2 which has the print button

Comment: do you want to print the contents of $('.modal-title_logindetail') ???

Comment: What I mean is, your `printArea2` function is potentially redundant. There's no need to call a new window and inject the printable content into it. You could call `window.print()` immediately and use CSS to control what is visible when printing and what is not. Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/5Lupoh1d/8/

Comment: This almost worked. The problem is this doesn't print out the content on the modal window alone. It also prints out the main page content, causing the modal window to sit on it.

Answer (score -1):

assuming you want to print div with class `$(".modal-title_logindetail")`

change your print button to

`<a class="btn btn-primary" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="printArea2();" >Print</a>`

try this

```
 function printArea2() {
        var contents = document.getElementsByClassName("modal-title_logindetail").innerHTML;
        var frame1 = document.createElement('iframe');
        frame1.name = "frame1";
        frame1.style.position = "absolute";
        frame1.style.top = "-1000000px";
        document.body.appendChild(frame1);
        var frameDoc = frame1.contentWindow ? frame1.contentWindow : frame1.contentDocument.document ? frame1.contentDocument.document : frame1.contentDocument;
        frameDoc.document.open();
        frameDoc.document.write('<html><head><title>DIV Contents</title>');
        frameDoc.document.write('</head><body>');
        frameDoc.document.write(contents);
        frameDoc.document.write('</body></html>');
        frameDoc.document.close();
        setTimeout(function () {
            window.frames["frame1"].focus();
            window.frames["frame1"].print();
            document.body.removeChild(frame1);
        }, 500);
        return false;
    }
```